# How to write code for Input Integer End Of File in C

Tags: c, eof

How can I input in `C language` at `EOF`?

I just want to know the process. I will be very thankful if someone elaborate it by example.

Comment: CRTL+D on linux for `scanf()` and family, replace D with Z on windows

Comment: or use the above username. :P

Comment: if you are solving online judge problem and the problem specifies that input will be terminated by `EOF` then you can simply take the input in while argument like `while( scanf("%d", &n ))`. On success, `scanf()` returns the number of items of the argument list successfully filled. so when it gets `EOF`, it will return `0` and the `while` loop will break.

Comment: Yes You got it. With getting input I have to print its result, so ? I have tried this :
`while( scanf("%d %d", &a, &b));{
        printf("%d\n", b-a);
    }` but it seems wrong

Answer (score 1):

You can have EOF with `CTRL+D` (for unix) or `CTRL+Z` (for Windows) from command line.

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh.: Should i delete my answer or leave it? Hold on questions answers are not upvoted..isn't it?